# How to change the default timeout configuration file for composer

Tags: ubuntu, php, vagrant, composer

I've been searching all over the internet and I can't seem to find any help as to where my composer's configuration file is saved to. Basically what I'm trying to do is change the `COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=300` to `COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=2000` as explained in this [blog post](http://www.papayasoft.com/2013/08/22/composer-process-timeout-when-fetching-large-repositories/). I'm currently running a vagrant box virtual Ubuntu server setup.
Does anyone know where I am to find this file in my Ubuntu server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems the answer to your question is in the comments of the link you posted:

qouting:

```
composer config --global process-timeout 2000
```